# rails how to show an array in the view with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Flowers and colors. I have set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

Through the console I can do:

```
q=Flower.first
q.colors
=> [#<Color id: 1, name: "Red", hex_code: "#FF0000", created_at: "2011-10-01 19:59:26", updated_at: "2011-10-01 19:59:26">, #<Color id: 3, name: "Blue", hex_code: "#0000FF", created_at: "2011-10-01 19:59:26", updated_at: "2011-10-01 19:59:26">]
```

and also:

```
q.color_ids
=> [1, 3]
```

How can I return the return color names? For example: `["Red", "Blue"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you an array of the color names:

```
q.colors.map(&:name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how to output Red, Blue, Green for example in the view?

Comment: Something like `<%= q.colors.map(&:name).join(', ') %>` if the variable in your view is named `q`